# Simple integral: $\int \frac {1+r}{-r^2+r-1} dr$.

Tags: integration

I was solving a much longer exercise, and while solving an ODE, I got this integral $$\int \frac {1+r}{-r^2+r-1} dr$$

I think this must be pretty simple, but  I couldn't solve it, my substitutions didn't work and the polynomial in the denumerator does not have real roots, so partial frac. decomp. looks quite messy.

How are do you solve the general integral:

$$
\int \frac {r+a}{dr^2+er+f}dr
$$

When the denumerator has no real roots?

Comment: How do complex roots prevent you from partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: One can still use partial fraction expansion.  If you don't wish to proceed along that line, then complete the square and use a trigonometric substitution.

Comment: Yes, it does not prevent me from using partial fracs, but I wanted a 'cleaner' way of doing it. @Dr.MV I got the denumerator in the form $a(r-t)^2+s$ before, but I didn't know how to proceed. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Write the denominator as $$-(r^2 - r + 1) = -\left(r - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4} .$$ This suggests splitting up the integral as
$$- \int \frac{r - \frac{1}{2}}{\left(r - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4}} dr - \frac{3}{2} \int \frac{dr}{\left(r - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4}} .$$ (If this sort of decomposition seems unmotivated or unfamiliar first substitute $u = r - \frac{1}{2}$, which gives
$$-\int \frac{u + \frac{3}{2}}{u^2 + \frac{3}{4}} du .)$$ In any case, one can then handle the two integrals using more primitive techniques.

Comment: Yep!  +1 This is the approach that I suggested in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Notice,  let $1+r=A\frac{d}{dr}(-r^2+r-1)+B=A(-2r+1)+B$

By comparing the corresponding coefficients, we get $A=-\frac{1}{2}$ & $B=\frac{3}{2}$

$$\int \frac{1+r}{-r^2+r-1}\ dr$$ $$=\int \frac{\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}(-2r+1)}{-r^2+r-1}\ dr$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}\int \frac{1}{-r^2+r-1}\ dr-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{-2r+1}{-r^2+r-1}\ dr$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}\int \frac{1}{-\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{3}{4}}\ dr-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{d(-r^2+r-1)}{-r^2+r-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$r^2-r+1 = \frac{r^3+1}{r+1}$, hence $r^2-r+1=(r-\omega)(r-\omega^2)$, with $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{6}\right)$.

By the residue theorem:
$$ \text{Res}\left(\frac{r+1}{r^2-r+1},r=\omega\right) = \frac{\omega+1}{2\omega},$$
$$ \text{Res}\left(\frac{r+1}{r^2-r+1},r=-\omega\right) = \frac{-\omega+1}{-2\omega},$$
hence the partial fraction decomposition is given by:
$$ \frac{r+1}{r^2-r+1} = \frac{1+\omega}{2\omega}\cdot\frac{1}{r-\omega}-\frac{1-\omega}{2\omega}\cdot\frac{1}{r+\omega}. $$
We may compute the primitive through the previous line, or through the trick:

$$ \frac{4r+4}{4r^2-4r+4} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2r-1}{r^2-r+1}+\frac{2}{1+\frac{1}{3}(2r-1)^2}$$
that gives:
$$ \int \frac{r+1}{r^2-r+1}\,dr = \frac{1}{2}\log(r^2-r+1)+\sqrt{3}\arctan\left(\frac{2r-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+C.$$